# Exibir hora completa AmCharts Gantt chart

Tags: javascript

Nesta URL [Gant Chart](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/gantt-chart/) é exibido um demo de um gráfico, listando nomes e exibindo horário de término de tarefas.

Ocorre que mesmo pesquisando, lendo a documentação, alterando formato (format), período (period), entre outras opções, não consegui exibir os segundos juntamente com a hora e minuto, nem fazer com que o script leve em conta minutos e segundos no cálculo de tarefas.

No demo atual, se qualquer funcionário começar atividade 12hs, e durar 3 horas, ele exibe o intervalo 12-15 no gráfico. Porém se a atividade iniciar 12hs e durar 1 hora, 20 minutos e 33 segundos, não exibe com tantos detalhes.

Comment: O correto é Gantt chart.

Comment: Podes sempre editar [edit] a pergunta e atualizar. Se fizesses um jsFidddle seria bem mais fácil ajudar-mos.

Comment: Não fiz um jsFiddle pois no link que informei há um botão azul no canto superior direito que permite editar e testar online, como no jsFiddle. Obrigado pela correção.